# Run Elastic Beanstalk commands after deploy

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, command, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deploy Symfony application on AWS. I use Elastic Beanstalk for that.
After deploy process I want to run some symfony commands : clear cache, update db, ...

So I create .ebextention with .config inside

```
commands:
  01updateComposer:
    command: export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update 1.0.0-alpha11
  cache:
    command: sudo php /var/www/html/bin/console cahce:clear --env=prod

option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name: COMPOSER_HOME
    value: /root
```

But it seams my `cache` command does not work or it works in wrong moment.

Could anybody help me please ?

**Updated :**
Actually I updated config file.
In /tmp right now I see end.txt, collect.txt, dump.txt. And They are OK.
But I dont have modifications on site. For example no assetics. It looks like commands run in wrong moment.

```
commands:
  01updateComposer:
    command: export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update 1.0.0-alpha11
  collect:
    command: sudo php /var/www/html/bin/console collect --nb=1 --env=prod >> /tmp/collect.txt
  assetic:
    command: sudo php /var/www/html/bin/console assets:install --symlink --env=prod >> /tmp/dump.txt
  dump:
    command: sudo php /var/www/html/bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod >> /tmp/dump.txt
  end:
    command: touch /tmp/end.txt

option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name: COMPOSER_HOME
    value: /root
```

I also triend container_commands instead of commands. That did help me.

**P.s.** I have only one instance EC2. So this could not be wront instance.

Comment: share logs http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html

Comment: @KushVyas I updated my question. Actually logs are ok. I even save some commands in /tmp/*.txt files.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with logging, and I think you need this to be in the container_commands section, not the commands section.

```
container_commands:
  01updateComposer:
    command: export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update 1.0.0-alpha11
  02collect:
    command: sudo php /var/www/html/bin/console collect --nb=1 --env=prod >> /tmp/collect.txt
  03assetic:
    command: sudo php /var/www/html/bin/console assets:install --symlink --env=prod >> /tmp/dump.txt
  04dump:
    command: sudo php /var/www/html/bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod >> /tmp/dump.txt
  05end:
    command: touch /tmp/end.txt

option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name: COMPOSER_HOME
    value: /root
```

You can see more details about my problems and solution [here](https://www.dativa.com/simplifying-filebeat-logging-with-elastic-beanstalk/).

Comment: commands are executed in alphabetical order so the ones you have above will be done the wrong way around. see above

Comment: Ahhhhh @Tom, probably this will help me. I'll try in a hour, thank u.

Comment: no, this did not help, I think by default an elastic beanstalk for symfony starts clear cache in the end of deploy. I can not find any solution. Probably I'll come back to this question when I'll be a little bit stronger in AWS skill.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in your `/var/log/eb-activity.log` file you'll see the order that everything is being executed in. In particular you'll see one moment in the deployment where the whole project is moved folder:

```
[2021-03-05T19:24:43.872Z] INFO  [17486] - [Application update app-1ee2-210305_192347@12/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/01_flip.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_staging_dir
  + EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=/var/app/ondeck
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_deploy_dir
  + EB_APP_DEPLOY_DIR=/var/app/current
  + '[' -d /var/app/current ']'
  + mv /var/app/current /var/app/current.old
  + mv /var/app/ondeck /var/app/current
  + nohup rm -rf /var/app/current.old
```

Certain commands (such as `php artisan view:cache`) need to be run *after* the project is moved, otherwise they won't function correctly.

To do this you can use [Elastic Beanstalk custom platform hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platform-hooks.html) (note: only with **Amazon Linux**, not the new nginx based Amazon Linux 2).

In one of your later `.config` files, you can simply add something like:

```
files:
   "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_z_post_deploy.sh":
      mode: "000755"
      owner: root
      group: root
      content: |
        #!/usr/bin/env bash
        echo "Running post.sh script"
        # Turn on maintenance mode
        #php /var/app/current/artisan down || true

        # Run database migrations
        php /var/app/current/artisan migrate --force
```

This will execute any commands under the `"/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_z_post_deploy.sh"` line in the "post" phase of the "appdeploy" stage. And 99_ will bring it towards the end of that (everything is executed alphabetically).

Again you can look in your `eb-activity.log` file to see where it's being executed. The example above will execute the shell script "post.sh".

For Amazon Linux 2 you need to use [Application deployment platform hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html).

This was all a bit late, but hopefully it helps. This is also not a bad guide that I found while writing this answer: [How To Use the Appdeploy Filesystem Hook](https://onica.com/blog/how-to/appdeploy-filesystem-hook/). It may help further.